# Embedding libVLC and the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) into a Qt application

Tags: qt, libvlc, chromium-embedded

I am using Qt to create a simple host application that uses VLC as a fullscreen video player (on a lower background plane), that is controlled by a HTML/JS/CSS-based on-screen display that runs on top of it (as a transparent foreground layer).

The plan is to embed libVLC, and the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF), so it's a cross-platform thing.

Is it possible for external HTML/JS content (i.e. ordinary web pages) rendered into the embedded CEF browser to directly cross-manipulate the libVLC instance, or is a separate, basic API needed as a "bridge" application in the Qt host?

For example: another developer creates a set of third-party HTML/JS screens which feature code invoking the underlying player to play source dvd:// or rtsp://?

NB: a) I'm aware Qt has it's own built-in web browser, but am looking to use CEF instead, b) i'm aware of the obvious security dangers of such an idea when implemented on an open network.

Comment: Were you able to do this?